# Create variable size array without pointers

Tags: c++

I have tried to read from a text file and using a loop put the two lines in the text file into a string array. But I want to make the array( in my code: string abc[5]) a variable size array without using pointers.I am fairly new to c++, Can someone please help me with that. Thanks in advance.

```
// reading a text file
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include<sstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
string line;
string iss_two;
int i = 0;

ifstream myfile("example.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{

    string token;
    stringstream iss;
    int x = 0;
    string abc[5];




        while (getline(myfile, line)) // first read entire line into a 
                                      //string
        {

                abc[i] = line;
                cout << abc[i] << "\n";
                i++;
                //  cout << token;
        }

            //iss.clear();


        cout << "\n" << abc[0];
        cout << "\n" << abc[1];

    myfile.close();

}

else cout << "Unable to open file";
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Use `std::vector`.

Comment: If other data structures are an option, use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: Use the standard: `std::vector` should be the first thing that pops up in your mind when you want any type of array or list like object in C++. You probably never want to use an `[]`-array and only *very* rarely a pointer of any kind in C++.

Comment: You have `#include <vector>` in your code, so why did you not use `std::vector`?

Comment: I tried using vector, but I was getting some errors when I used that.

Comment: What errors? And how were u using it?

Comment: Initialized vector as : vector <string> abc;                                                     In my for loop,I have used this code instead :  abc.push_back(i) = line;            The for loop is giving me an error. I don't think I am doing it right.

Comment: @SharanyaRamkrishna use `abc.push_back(line)` instead

Comment: Thank you very much guys. Working perfect :)

Answer (score 1):

An array (as the word is used in C++ language) can not have a variable size. Its size never changes during its lifetime. The size of an array *variable* must be known at compile time, but the size of a dynamically allocated array can be determined at run time.

Dynamic allocation requires the use of pointer variables. You can of course hide the use of pointers by containing the functionality within a class. Such class that abstracts dynamic allocation of arrays already exist in the C++ standard library: `std::vector`. I recommend that you use it.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make the array( in my code: string abc[5]) a variable size array without using pointers.

If you ***have*** to use arrays, you can simulate a variable size by preallocating a really big array at compile time and then having checks to ensure you don't go over that amount (i.e. like getting a line of credit).

```
const int MAX_ARRAY_SIZE = 100000;
int main() {
   ...
   int linesRead = 0;
   string abc[MAX_ARRAY_SIZE];
      ...
      while (linesRead<MAX_ARRAY_SIZE && getline(myfile, line)) 
      {
          abc[linesRead] = line;
          cout << abc[linesRead] << "\n";
          linesRead++;
      }

      if(linesRead>=MAX_ARRAY_SIZE){
           cout << "Warning!  You hit the maximum array size for your "
                << "string.  There may still be text in your file\n";
      }

      ...

      cout << "\n" << abc[0];
      cout << "\n" << abc[1];
      ...
}
```

As pointed out by others, the std::vector library is setup for this kind of thing with C++.  Also, the downfalls here include preallocating more memory than you need or not preallocating the amount you need.  So, while you may use this approach to get started in debugging or if you have some additional insight into the maximum array that you would run across, you would std::vector or dynamic memory allocation otherwise.